# why my popovers from bootstrap 5 return a Uncaught TypeError?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular-cli, bootstrap-5

I want to use Bootstrap 5 popovers in my Angular app.

Here's what I do:

**my index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>my website</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    var popover = new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('.popoverable'), {
      container: 'body'
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary popoverable" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Bottom popover">
  Popover on bottom
</button>
```

Then on my page I see my styled button, but the popover doesn't appear and in the console I get a `Uncaught TypeError: this._element is undefined`.

Does anybody have a solution to my issue ?

Comment: i think your javascript is trying to run before the page renders fully, place your popover javascript in document load and give it a try again

Comment: what do you mean where should I put it ? in my "app.component.ts" ? @Tch

Comment: got same problem with BS 5 modals. Added -bs to data attributes, still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit old, but I just ran into this and figured it out so I thought I'd share for posterity.

Turns out this happens when you call `new bootstrap.Popover` *before* the element is on the page. It doesn't work for "future" elements to be rendered on the page, which in your case I believe must happen through  Angular in your `<app-root>` element. When the `<script>` tag executes, there is no `.popoverable` in the DOM.

In my case, I had to make sure to defer `Popover`'s initialization til after `DOMContentLoaded`.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  let popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('.popoverable')
  );
  let popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl);
  });
});
```

In your case, you would have to make it happen *after* the `app-component` has been rendered into the DOM (I'm not familiar enough with Angular to tell you where that would be, but you'd need to hook into the initialization life-cycle of the component, and perhaps also make sure to "disconnect" the Popover if/when the `app-component` gets unloaded in order to avoid memory leaks).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the beta version of bootstrap 5 which doesn't require jQuery and uses its own javascript file.

To initialize bootstrap's js you have to use `bs`.

Replace:

- `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle`
- `data-placement` to `data-bs-placement`
- `data-content` to `data-bs-content`

Your code:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary popoverable" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Bottom popover">
  Popover on bottom
</button>
```

Updated Code:

```html
<button type="button" class="my-5 d-block btn btn-secondary popoverable" data-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-content="Bottom popover">
  Popover on bottom
</button>
```

[image]

Comment: it didn't solved the problem but thank you for pointing that issue

Comment: it's the only problem that I can see in your code right now. Check once if javascript is loading or not.